# Save order in jquery sortable connected lists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

My code is work fine.. but I like save the order in Mysql of the second column as soon as I make any changes... The PHP programming I can do, just do not know how to send the changes to php file

See my code ( complete code in: http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/wMnsa/ )

```
        <ul id="unassigned_list" class="connected_sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="draggable_area">Item 1</div><div class="click_area">&#8594;</div><div class="cl"></div></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="draggable_area">Item 2</div><div class="click_area">&#8594;</div><div class="cl"></div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="recipients_list" class="connected_sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight"><div class="draggable_area">Item 3</div><div class="click_area">&#8592;</div><div class="cl"></div></li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight"><div class="draggable_area">Item 4</div><div class="click_area">&#8592;</div><div class="cl"></div></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
$("#unassigned_list, #recipients_list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
    items: "li",
    handle: ".draggable_area",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        updateLi(ui.item);
    }
}).disableSelection().on("click", ".click_area", function() {
    // First figure out which list the clicked element is NOT in...
    var otherUL = $("#unassigned_list, #recipients_list").not($(this).closest("ul"));
    var li = $(this).closest("li");

    // Move the li to the other list. prependTo() can also be used instead of appendTo().
    li.detach().appendTo(otherUL);

    // Finally, switch the class on the li, and change the arrow's direction.
    updateLi(li);
});

function updateLi(li) {
    var clickArea = li.find(".click_area");
    if (li.closest("ul").is("#recipients_list")) {
        li.removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        clickArea.html('&#8592;');
    } else {
        li.removeClass("ui-state-highlight").addClass("ui-state-default");
        clickArea.html('&#8594;');
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Give all the elements unique ids and use the serialize or toArray methods of plugin as documented in the api. Just a matter of determining which event is best to do it in for your use case

Comment: Yes.. i add unique id using php.. but i dont know how serialize and send to another php file

Comment: Oh... use `$.ajax` to send data to php endpoint

Comment: Guys, I know I have to use ajax, but I do not know how to write the code ... I tried that way:

$("#unassigned_list, #recipients_list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
    items: "li",
    handle: ".draggable_area",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        updateLi(ui.item);
  var order = $('#recipients_list').sortable('serialize'); 
  $("#info").load("order.php?order="+order);
    }

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and give upvote it to help other programmers for finding a solution when they have same issue. The majority of programmers see accepted or upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `id` to elements and adding code below to `sortable`:

```
update: function() {
    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    alert(order);
  }
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/19hedcjm/)